# Cart items empty inside plugin for Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, cart, configurable-product

I have tried many methods to get cart items inside plugin for `"Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"` . I am trying to add additional cart item data to the "getJsonConfig" function.

No matter what I do, the cart always seems to be empty even though there are items in the cart.

```
<?php
namespace VENDORNAME\VENDORMODULE\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type;

use VENDORNAME\VENDORMODULE\Helper\Data as Helper;

class Configurable
{
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_jsonDecoder;
    protected $_jsonEncoder;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_cartHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        Helper $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_cartHelper = $cartHelper;
    }

    protected function _getCartProducts() {
        $cartProducts = array();
        $cartItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        if($cartItems && sizeof($cartItems)) {
            foreach($cartItems as $item) {
                if($item->getProductType() == 'simple' && $item->getParentItemId()) {
                    $cartProducts[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        return $cartProducts;
    }

    public function afterGetJsonConfig($subject, $result) {
        $config = $this->_jsonDecoder->decode($result);
        $config['cart'] = $this->_getCartProducts();
        return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to retrieve the cart items here? Or why it is missing? 
Do I need a $cartId variable or something to load the cart first? 
Is it possible this has something to do with caching?

I have no idea why the cart appears empty here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can getting Cart/Quote data using this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// get quote items 
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// get quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

Comment: Nope, it is still always empty. No cart items.

Comment: have you seen items in cart page ?

Comment: Yes, items are in cart page and mini-cart

Comment: then it should be work as per my answer

Comment: also you check cart item count : <?php  echo count($items); ?>

Comment: I really think it might have something to do with the product options being cached... but im not sure. It is not working with your answer.